# Can you tell whats wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript

Its purpose:
It is supposed to create a div, then make it slowly move to a random location.

The problem:
I tried pasting this into the Inspect Element console. 
It only creates the div then stops. There are no errors, nothing to indicate whats wrong. This is really bugging me.

If you want to see whats happening, you can press CTRL + SHIFT + J and paste the code into the inspect element console.

The code:

```
var l = document.createElement('div'); 
l.style.height = '100px';
l.style.width = '100px';
l.style.position = 'relative';
l.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
l.id = 'di';
document.body.appendChild(l);
var lef = 0;
var to = 0;
var p = Math.random() * 1000;
var o = Math.random() * 400;
var h = setInterval(function () {
if (lef > p) {
    di.style.top = to + 'px';
    to = to + 1;
    if (to > o) {
        p = Math.random() * 1000;
        o = Math.random() * 400
    }
} else if (to > o) {
    di.style.left = lef + 'px';
    lef = lef + 1;
    if (lef > p) {
        p = Math.random() * 1000;
        o = Math.random() * 400
    } else {
        di.style.left = lef + 'px';
        lef = lef + 1;
        di.style.top = to + 'px';
        to = to + 1;
    }
}
}, 100)
```

Comment: There's one obvious issue; you should use `l` instead of `di` to reference the added `<div>`.

Comment: You actually never entering one of the cases in the if-statement. The lowest number `Math.random()` is returning is 0 and therefore `lef` or `to` will never be greater than `p` or `o`. [Math.random Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: @Bojangles That came off as a little harsh, but I agree. You shouldn't make a big deal about your age. If you put it in your profile, people could gear their words toward your age group, but that's up to you. Don't discuss it in your questions (you could just put that information in your profile description without giving away a real number). Jack is right about the `<div>`. You set `l.id` to be `'di'`, but `'di'` cannot be used as a variable reference, which is what you are trying to do with `di.style.top`, etc. **Edit**: looks like you added that age description to your profile. Nice!

Comment: Jack it true but try `jQuery` for this purposes. It's designed for doing things like transitions effects and ... .

Comment: @HamidFzM True, jQuery was designed to make some things like transitions/effects easier, but jQuery is a learning curve. I think that for all intensive purposes, trying to do something 'from scratch' like this is a good place to start, especially if he's new to programming. Otherwise he'll never really learn JavaScript and will be stuck with jQuery as a dependency for everything he does.

Comment: Seconding Hamid's suggestion -- while there are many times jQ is suggested in Stack Overflow answers and it's actually overkill, this is one case where I think it's a very solid recommendation (on the other hand it's great that a young coder is learning to manage the DOM directly).

Comment: @HamidFzM jQuery isn't where you should start when you learn about JavaScript programming.

Comment: I've worked out [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kerinuwo/1/watch?js,output) that may come closer to what you want? I've kept it simple.

Comment: Read these articles to [learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can provider more useful context information (and help yourself). For example, if you added `console.log` statements and inspect the values of the variables, would probably have found the issue yourself.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice forgive me for going off topic, but it may be helpful to know that the phrase you wanted is "all intents and purposes"

Comment: I strongly suggest you create an account on plunker or jsfiddle and provide your code sample there. You'll certainly get more constructive answers this way. As for your code, besides from the fact that you don't state what you think the problem is, there are a few obvious logical errors in your code.

Comment: @Semicolon True. That's a 3 A.M. *too-tired-to-think-straight-and-still-mindlessly-browsing-SO* error. These types of things happen pretty often to me after midnight!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about what logic you are using to generate the `left` and `top` of the `div` element, but I have made a demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/cnLFu/) which shows up the `div` changing its position continuously. The problem in you code is the way you are using `di` which is incorrect. Instead you should it like:

```
var div_element = document.getElementById('di');
//and then using it like
div_element.style.left= some_value+"px";
div_element.style.top= some_value+"px";
```

Here is the compete JS code of the example I have made:

```
var l = document.createElement('div'); 
l.style.height = '100px';
l.style.width = '100px';
l.style.position = 'relative';
l.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
l.id = 'di';
document.body.appendChild(l);

var div_elem = document.getElementById(l.id);
//div_elem.style.top = "100px";
//alert(div_elem.id);
var h = setInterval(function () {
   div_elem.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)+"px"; //Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);  Generates random number between 1 and 100
   div_elem.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1)+"px"; //Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1);  Generates random number between 1 and 200
   //console.log('top = '+div_elem.style.top);
   //console.log('left = '+div_elem.style.left); 
}, 100)
```

Hope this helps.